# Error exporting MySQL table to open document Spreadsheet

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, suse

I am getting the following error when exporting a MySQL table to open document spreadsheet. My OS is linux Suse. phpMyAdmin version is 4.8.4. Kindly help.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PhpMyAdmin\gzcompress() in /srv/www/htdocs/pma/libraries/classes/ZipExtension.php:224
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /srv/www/htdocs/pma/libraries/classes/OpenDocument.php(175): PhpMyAdmin\ZipExtension-createFile(Array, Array)
>
> #1 /srv/www/htdocs/pma/libraries/classes/Plugins/Export/ExportOds.php(155): PhpMyAdmin\OpenDocument::create('application/vnd...', Array)
>
> #2 /srv/www/htdocs/pma/export.php(504): PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\ExportOds->exportFooter()
>
> #3 {main} thrown in /srv/www/htdocs/pma/libraries/classes/ZipExtension.php on line 224

Comment: *Call to **undefined function** PhpMyAdmin\gzcompress()* - what is unclear in this message?

Comment: I'm missing some package or something? I have zlib and gzip installed already

Comment: You must define used function/module/library explicitly. Installed != implicitly available.

Comment: I installed php7-zlib and turned on zlib compression in php.ini, zlib.output_compression = On, and it worked